# Select edge ring in UV mode?

Tags: uv, selection-tools

Is it possible? [Edit: apart from manually, edge by edge!]

I'm going through a tutorial. The example UV I'm working on is an unwrapped strip from a ball.

Selecting the strip rings (e.g. to straighten them by scaling) proves incredibly challenging! Here's what I tried and didn't work:

1) the select ring function from the 3d view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>) doesn't work in UV window

2) using "sync UV with model" gets you the selection from the 3d view but: it'll disappear as soon as you disable sync or <s>it will scale the model</s> you can't scale on "individual origins" if you scale UV edges with sync enabled

3) the Circle or Border selection tools (in UV) do not select in "crossing" mode - i.e. you can't select rings only by drawing a flat narrow selection (you can only select rings AND loops by fatfingering it)

4) the Circle or Border selection tools - if you decide to subract the loops and leave the rings - now, weirdly, will work in "crossing" mode thus subtracting a loop and all your rings from your selection

[image: A view of the UV map - disregard the selection]

Comment: Regarding to the step 2 do you mean vertices of the mesh are scaled in 3D space when you scale vertices of UV map ? I couldn't repeat that; the only thing I could do - to scale verts on map and adjacent ones of mesh continue staying in place

Comment: @Mr Zak, actually you are correct, I'm talking rubbish - I've edited main post accordingly. Still... this is no way to solve the problem as can't seem to scale around "individual origins" in UV editor.

Comment: Don't use Ctrl - Just use Alt + RMB

Comment: @RickRiggs `Alt`+`RMB` selects *[edge loop](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges.html#edge-loops)*, while the OP asks for selecting *[edge ring](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges.html#edge-rings)* on UV map.

Comment: My mistake, sorry guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so it seems fair to answer this - since the question was about *selecting edge ring in UV editor*.

The way to do this is by:

- enabling "keep UVs and edit mode mesh selection in sync" (button in the header of UV editor)
- just Ctrl+Alt+RMB an edge in 3D editor (a derived UV selection will show up in UV editor)

Were the question about *straightening the resulting selection*, it would seem there is no way to do this for now (version 2.67b).

[Thanks to Mr Zak for clearing the confusion.]

Comment: Seemed like the OP was asking how to select the boundary of a UV island rather than a 3D edge ring. That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do anyway... no luck yet.

Comment: I found out how to select all UV island boundaries here: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360492-select-seams

Answer (score 2):

Since this answer has already missed the mark, based on my own misunderstanding of what was happening in the Author's question, I figured that I would at least attempt to help anyone who is running across this thread, line up their unwrap of a sphere to equalize their faces.

Please refer to the answer that the Author has already solved as the accurate answer, and use this only as a helper.

**In the 3D Viewport**

1. Select an edge that you want to mark a seam at.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> >> Mark Seam.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+RightClick at each edge loop.
4. <kbd>U</kbd> >> Unwrap.

**In the UV / Image Editor**

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+RightClick at one edge loop.
2. <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.
3. <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, Line up to desired image location.
4. **Repeat Steps 1 THRU 3 on the other edge loop.**
5. Select the middle-most vertex of the smaller edge loop.
6. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> >> Cursor to Selected.
7. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+RightClick at the smaller edge loop.
8. <kbd>(QWERTY Period) .</kbd> to set scale origin to the 2D Cursor.
9. <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, Move mouse until Visual alignment is sufficiently close.
10. <kbd>(QWERTY Comma) ,</kbd> to set scale origin to Median.

[image]

Comment: If I select all and weld, it welds all the faces/verts/edges into a single vert. I can't even see a threshold. Did you mean remove doubles? Anyway the mesh itself wasn't split, it was one piece - no doubles.

Comment: Maybe it was just a display thing then, sorry! When I was looking at your selected verts, and the fall-off of the highlighted color, it looked as if there were doubles; because some of the edges connected to the highlighted verts did not show the highlighted color.

Comment: Since you are correct about me misunderstanding the question, I would not expect any sort of credit here, but I would still like to help you and anyone else having similar issues that would look at this thread get to the desired outcome. So I will post an appending edit to my answer.

Comment: Voting it up, 'cause it's a nice helpful example which probably covers the majority of use cases. (Sometimes the trick is in asking the right question - and mine was based on _expectations_ - what works in Blender's 3D view and I imagined I could also do in UV view..)